# SQL return incremented number

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Hi I want to create a SQL function to return either 1 if a name in a column is unique, otherwise if that name is not unique then return an increment of 1. Here is what it should look lile:

```
NAME | Number
A    | 1
B    | 1
C    | 1
C    | 2
C    | 3
D    | 1
E    | 1
```

The problem I am having is getting the number to increment.

Comment: SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL, ...? Do you really want a function or do you need this in a query?

Comment: Sorry I should have said it was SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ANSI SQL:

```
select name,
       row_Number() over (partition by name order by name) as number
from your_table
```

Comment: This works, I just had to change the null to name because I was getting the error `Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions.`

Comment: @user2164702: thanks for the feedback. I always forget that limitation in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

If it's SQL Server, have a look here, at the Section C: Using ROW_NUMBER() with PARTITION:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

```
SELECT 
name
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) number
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (NAME CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO #TEST 
SELECT 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D'

SELECT NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) AS Number
FROM #TEST
```